# How to follow systemd unit log?

Tags: linux, logging, systemd

I have a running systemd unit and I want to follow it's log.

I know I can show unit's log by using:

```
journalctl -u my_unit.service
```

But that only prints current logs without following them.

I know I can also follow `systemd` logs by using:

```
journalctl -f
```

But that spams the output by following all known logs, so I have to search for what I'm interested in.

A temporary solution seems to be piping followed logs to grep filtering the output, but that's not very systematic solution:

```
journalctl -f | grep "what i'm interested in"
```

**Isn't there a command for following logs of certain unit?**

What I've tried, but didn't work:

```
journalctl -uf my_unit.service
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've found out I'm using the arguments in a bad order. Logs can actually be followed for a single unit by using:

```
journalctl -fu my_unit.service
```

Other working variations:

```
journalctl -f -u my_unit.service
journalctl -u my_unit.service -f
```

From [`journalctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html) manual:

> `-u`, `--unit=UNIT|PATTERN`
>
>   Show messages for the specified systemd unit
>   *`UNIT`*
>   (such as a service unit), or for any of the units matched by
>   *`PATTERN`*
>   . If a pattern is specified, a list of unit names found in the journal is compared with the specified pattern and all that match are used. 
>     For each unit name, a match is added for messages
>     from the unit ("
>   `_SYSTEMD_UNIT=UNIT`
>   "),
>     along with additional matches for messages from systemd and messages
>     about coredumps for the specified unit.
>
> This parameter can be specified multiple times.
>
> `-f, --follow`
>
>   Show only the most recent journal entries, and continuously print new entries as they are appended to the journal.